# A older compiled version of Wireshark(1.10.1) is not getting installed in newer ubuntu (version 16)

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, wireshark, libgcrypt

I have a deb file for wireshark 1.10.1 which was compiled with some extra flags for remote capture. The compilation was done in Ubuntu 12 few years ago. In ubuntu 14 it works perfectly. But when I am trying it in Ubuntu 16 it get stuck with a dependency issue.

```
wireshark-common depends on libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.6); however:
  Package libgcrypt11 is not installed.
 wireshark-common depends on libgnutls26 (>= 2.7.14-0); however:
  Package libgnutls26 is not installed.
```

However in my fresh ubuntu 16 system, when I did 'dpkg -l | grep libgcrypt', the result is

```
ii  libgcrypt20:amd64                          1.6.5-2                                             amd64        LGPL Crypto library - runtime library
```

and for 'dpkg -l | grep libgnutls' , i got

```
ii  libgnutls-dev:amd64                        3.4.10-4ubuntu1.1                                   amd64        GNU TLS library - development files
ii  libgnutls-openssl27:amd64                  3.4.10-4ubuntu1.1                                   amd64        GNU TLS library - OpenSSL wrapper
ii  libgnutls30:amd64                          3.4.10-4ubuntu1.1                                   amd64        GNU TLS library - main runtime library
ii  libgnutlsxx28:amd64                        3.4.10-4ubuntu1.1                                   amd64        GNU TLS library - C++ runtime library
```

My question is whether the problem is from the version mismatch only? If so, can it be solved by soft linking or some other method so that hassle of recompiling can be avoided.

Comment: This does not help perhaps: `sudo apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: no..i tried it already.
sudo apt-get -f install wireshark-common_1.10.1_amd64.deb

[sudo] password for user1:

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wireshark-common_1.10.1_amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'wireshark-common_1.10.1_amd64.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wireshark-common_1.10.1_amd64.deb'